# Order grouped data by record Id and date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a data set like below. I want to identify the dates where `StyleId` changes. Since the data set is not in the correct order, my observations go wrong.

For example, there should be only 1 change (on 2016-04-07 Style Id changes from 530 to 526) but according to the the current order, it shows Style Id changes on 07th from 530 to 526, again on the same day from 526 to 530 and finally on 19th it changes from 530 to 526. Please guide me on ordering this data set in the correct way.

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73PX9.png)

Update:

Using `DESC` in

```
SELECT * 
FROM SewingPlan 
ORDER BY SewingDate, StyleId DESC
```

is not a valid solution because it won't be applicable for every scenario.

Update2:

I have posted a solution as an answer which I came up with. Anyone with a better solution?

Comment: Can you provide sample code/query rather than a screenshot of your data set?  What have you tried?

Comment: what other columns do you have. what's inserting these records, what's the trigger? What's the logic? so many quesitons...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Query is a complex one.. bit difficult to make it simple enough to post here. However, this can be taken as the ultimate result data set which I need to order. how can I achieve it starting from 'SELECT * FROM SewingPlan
ORDER BY SewingDate,StyleId'

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM SewingPlan ORDER BY SewingDate,StyleId' only retrieves the data set in above order

Comment: Just want to try achieving the expected result without additional columns. (mostly because other columns are not useful in the ordering.) And I'm not inserting these records. They are already there in the DB. I need to reorder them to track the changes

Comment: Can `StyleId` change to any value, whether it's a higher or a lower one? So could its sequence be like: 530, 530, 526, 526, 526, 529, 529, 529, 525...? If the answer is yes, then it's quite complex, because given two rows for a date, you don't know how to sort them unless you know the previous row's `StyleId`. Is it possible one of these numbers to appear only once? For example: 530, 530, 526, 529, 529? May there be two changes in one day? Or may a change occur at midnight so the number is not repeated for the next day?

Comment: Andrew, That's quite the question you asked. Thanks for the nice analysis. Actually all the scenarios you mentioned are possible. StyleId is not in any order. And There can be two changes in one day also. As you mentioned, sorting is possible only based on the previous row's style Id. I have posted an answer based on this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution & Assumption:** SewingPlan table has a primary key. It is SewingPlan_ID. It is automatically increasing one by one. **So minimum value should be earliest one.**

This query will return changed primary key.

```
SELECT MIN(SewingPlan_ID) FROM SewingPlan Group BY StyleId
```

Lets say you got 1000 as a answer for a styleId. After that you can query what ever now you know primary key. you can join or nested query whatever.

```
SELECT * FROM SewingPlan where SewingPlan_ID=1000
```

Let me know your response?

Update: 
Also you can use :easily get the changed date for styleId

```
SELECT MIN(SewingDate) FROM SewingPlan Group BY StyleId
```

Comment: Thanks Sanka for a good solution. But I tried this using the primary key. Problem is the minimum value is not always the earliest. There can be occurrences where the user have entered records backdating. Hence the primary keys are also not in order. That's why I didn't mention the primary key column here.

Comment: I believe I have misguided you when I asked the question. Even though I want to get the changed date, there are many complex things to be done along with it. It's not possible for me to explain the whole scenario. Just know that ORDERING the records is a must.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using cursors and achieved the desired output (without additional columns). This is maybe a dirty way of getting it done. Posting the query for future references. More optimized and better solutions are welcome.

```
DECLARE @id int, @SewingDate datetime, @StyleId int,@PreviousStyleId int

SELECT TOP 1  @PreviousStyleId = StyleId 
FROM    SewingPlan
ORDER BY SewingDate,StyleId

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #TempTable

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(SewingDate DATETIME,StyleId INT,Sequence INT)

DECLARE sewingdates
CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  SewingDate
    FROM    SewingPlan
    GROUP BY SewingDate
    ORDER BY SewingDate

OPEN sewingdates
FETCH NEXT 
FROM sewingdates 
INTO @SewingDate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN   

    INSERT INTO #TempTable (SewingDate, StyleId, Sequence)
    SELECT  SewingDate,StyleId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (CASE WHEN StyleId = @PreviousStyleId THEN '1' ELSE StyleId END))
    FROM    SewingPlan
    WHERE   SewingDate = @SewingDate    

    SELECT TOP 1 @PreviousStyleId = StyleId
    FROM    SewingPlan
    WHERE   SewingDate = @SewingDate    
    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN StyleId = @PreviousStyleId THEN '1' ELSE StyleId END) DESC

FETCH NEXT 
FROM sewingdates 
INTO @SewingDate
END
CLOSE sewingdates
DEALLOCATE sewingdates

SELECT * FROM #TempTable

GO
```

[Ordered Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVpzI.png)